# JavaScript: Format whole numbers using toLocaleString()

Tags: javascript

I'm using the `Number.prototype.toLocaleString()` function to add commas to whole numbers.  Documentation for it can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).

I am writing it as follows:

```
Number(data).ToLocaleString('en');
```

In Firefox/Chrome the number is displayed like `123,456,789`.  However, in IE it is displayed like `123,456,789.00`.

**1. Why is IE adding in the decimal point values?**

**2. How can I remove the decimal point values?**

Rather than creating/using a custom function, I'm really just wondering if there is an option that I can add to ToLocaleString() like `en, nodecimal`.  If that option is not available, I will consider a custom function.

Comment: It really outputs that in Firefox ?

Comment: 1) that's not valid JS. 2) `toLocaleString` is "implementation-dependent" according to the spec.

Comment: @adeneo Yep. Using v26

Comment: @p.s.w.g Woops.  Added an extra period.  Changed it.

Comment: Don't forget to check the regional settings on your computer.  I can change whether ie8 displays decimal points or not via "No. of digits after decimal".  In windows 7, it's in control panel --> region and language --> formats --> additional settings --> numbers.  ie8 seems to ignore the string supplied to toLocaleString (not against spec).

Comment: @HarryPehkonen.  I understand that I could change my computer settings to achieve the desired affect personally, but my goal is to change it for all end users who come to my website.  I have no control over their computer settings.

Comment: There is an option you can use, it's called `maximumFractionDigits` and you need to set it to `0`. You need to set `minimumFractionDigits` as well. See specification [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString). For example: `Number(123534.34).toLocaleString('da-DK',{style:'currency',currency:"DKK",maximumFractionDigits:0, minimumFractionDigits:0});` will display `123.534 kr.` instead of `123.534,34 kr.`

Comment: @AlexBowyer Thanks, but Guy already mentioned those two parameters in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51779528/1751883)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

How about [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString):

```
const sum = 1000;

const formatted = sum.toLocaleString("en", {   
    minimumFractionDigits: 0,
    maximumFractionDigits: 0,
});

console.log(formatted);
```

for:

```
// 1,000
```

Or if you're into the money stuff:

```
const sum = 1000;

const formatted = sum.toLocaleString("en", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "USD",
    minimumFractionDigits: 0,
    maximumFractionDigits: 0,
});

console.log(formatted);
```

for:

```
// $1,000
```

Replace `"en"` with one of the [supported](https://gist.github.com/Josantonius/b455e315bc7f790d14b136d61d9ae469) language tags*. For instance:

```js
'en-US'
// en => a BCP 47 tag that represents a language
// US => a ISO_3166-1 Alpha-2 subtag that represents a country | optional
```

Replace `"USD"` with a [ISO-4217](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217#Active_codes) currency code. For instance:

```js
'EUR'
// EUR is currency #978 on the active currencies codes list. 
// The result would be a numeric value prefixed by the € sign
```

* Further information is available on the [BCP 47](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag#List_of_common_primary_language_subtags) and [ISO 3166-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1) wikis.

Comment: Was `minimumFractionDigits` and `maximumFractionDigits` recently introduced?  I don't believe that was an option back when I asked the question.

Comment: @Keven You're probably right. From googling it, it seems that in 2015 it was already available https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581011/how-to-use-tolocalestring-and-tofixed2-in-javascript so perhaps around a year after you asked

Answer (score 12):

1) Refer to Andy E's (1) answer.

2) Andy E's solution works on IE 10 and lower but seems to cause the wrong outputs on modern browsers (try it in the console with any number). Here is a safer string manipulation:

```
Number(data).toLocaleString().split('.')[0];
```

*Andy I would have added this as a comment to your answer but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: This works fine when you know the separator is a dot ("."), what about commas as in French and others?

Comment: This will not work in certain locales. For example: `Number(123534.34).toLocaleString('da-DK',{style:'currency',currency:"DKK"})` which displays as `123.534,34 kr.`. Instead you should set the `maximumFractionDigits` and `minimumFractionDigits` options to `0`, as specified [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString). For example: `Number(123534.34).toLocaleString('da-DK',{style:'currency',currency:"DKK",maximumFractionDigits:0, minimumFractionDigits:0});` which will display `123.534 kr.`

Answer (score 11):

Which version of IE did you test in?  In IE 10 and lower, `toLocaleString` is based on the ECMAScript specification, which states that the function should be "implementation dependant".  In IE 11, it is based on the [ECMA Internationalization API](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-402.htm), and should be consistent with Firefox 26.

To remove the decimal values in IE 10 and lower (and potentially, other older browsers), you'll have to resort to string manipulation:

```
Number(data).toLocaleString('en').slice(0, -3);
```

There's also [a polyfill available](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js) for this API, which will work for IE 10 and lower.  Including it at the moment is a little tricky, since the browser/minified build contains no actual data (because it would be huge).  The data is provided separately in JSON or JSONP format, so that you can download the correct data for the user currently browsing your site.

Comment: I'm testing in IE9 and below and need to support IE 10 and below so it looks like I'll need to manipulate then.

Comment: This will not work in certain locales. For example: `Number(123534.34).toLocaleString('da-DK',{style:'currency',currency:"DKK"})` which displays as `123.534,34 kr.`. Instead you should set the `maximumFractionDigits` and `minimumFractionDigits` options to `0`, as specified [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString). For example: `Number(123534.34).toLocaleString('da-DK',{style:'currency',currency:"DKK",maximumFractionDigits:0, minimumFractionDigits:0});` which will display `123.534 kr.`

Answer (score 3):

Number(data).toLocaleString().replace(/\D\d\d$/, ''); should cover any locale and browser.

Comment: Great solution. Retains the thousand separator. and doesn't throw a tantrum if a number doesn't contain decimals (in later browsers).

Comment: This will not work in certain locales. For example: `Number(123534.34).toLocaleString('da-DK',{style:'currency',currency:"DKK"})` which displays as `123.534,34 kr.`. Instead you should set the `maximumFractionDigits` and `minimumFractionDigits` options to `0`, as specified [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString). For example: `Number(123534.34).toLocaleString('da-DK',{style:'currency',currency:"DKK",maximumFractionDigits:0, minimumFractionDigits:0});` which will display `123.534 kr.`

Comment: In the OP's question, isn't that what he would want? He's only using whole numbers and IE is adding the .00 - or in your case ",00"