# How to use toLocaleString() and tofixed(2) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I do this in JavaScript?

```
var num = 2046430; 
num.toLocaleString();

will give you "2,046,430";
```

What I have tried is:

```
var num = 2046430; 
num.toLocaleString().toFixed(2);
```

*Expected Output*

> "2,046,430.00"

Comment: toFixed() is only for number not strings

Answer (score 370, accepted):

Taken from MDN:

**Syntax**

`numObj.toLocaleString([locales [, options]])`

`toLocaleString` takes 2 arguments. The first is the locale, the second are the options. As for the options, you are looking for:

> minimumFractionDigits
>
> The minimum number of fraction digits to use.
>   Possible values are from 0 to 20; the default for plain number and
>   percent formatting is 0; the default for currency formatting is the
>   number of minor unit digits provided by the ISO 4217 currency code
>   list (2 if the list doesn't provide that information).

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

To be able to set the options without setting the locale, you can pass undefined as first argument:

```
var num = 2046430;
num.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: 2}) // 2,046,430.00
```

However this also allows the fraction to be longer than 2 digits. So we need to look for one more option called `maximumFractionDigits`. (Also on that MDN page)

```
var num = 2046430.123;
num.toLocaleString(undefined, {
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  maximumFractionDigits: 2
}) // 2,046,430.12
```

Comment: Also one more thing. You can do things like this for convenience reasons: http://jsfiddle.net/st31wm96/2/ becaue it could be quite repetitive to always write this by hand.

Comment: this is not same as toFixed(2).. Example `33.6.toLocaleString(undefined, { minimumFractionDigits: 2,  maximumFractionDigits: 2 })` will be equal "33.6" not "33.60"

Comment: @Zalaboza, I just tested in the console and your example code does indeed show "33.60". The accepted answer works as expected.

Comment: toLocaleString('en-US', {
                minimumFractionDigits: 2,
                maximumFractionDigits: 2
            })

Answer (score 1):

I came here because I would like to show the currency symbol (R$) in addition show two digits after the decimal point in the result.

Initially I was trying the following code:

```
`Amount ${(gas * litros).toFixed(2)
  .toLocaleString('pt-BR', {style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL'})}`
```

Expected output: Total a pagar **R$** 20.95

Output: Total a pagar 20.95

So, with the answers above, I tried without the `toFixed()`:

```
`Total a pagar ${(gas * litros)
    .toLocaleString('pt-BR', {style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL', minimumFractionDigits: 2})}`
```

Output: Total a pagar **R$** 15,80

Answer (score 0):

@Sebastian Nette's [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31581206/5964556) was, for some reason not working for me to handle numbers like `"1,230.05"`, where it was a string with a comma.

I ended up going with the following:

```
var num = "1,230.05";
parseFloat(num.replace(",", "")).toFixed(2);
```

It just manually strips the commas before parsing as a float and running toFixed().

Comment: It seems like you're solving a different problem. Sebastian starts with a number and formats it as a locale string with 2 digits after the decimal. Your answer starts with a locale string and formats it as a non-localized number with 2 digits after the decimal.