# Issue with using toLocaleString in React input with decimals

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a react input box that I want to format so that it will show a number displayed as a currency. It is currently showing commas but when I try and add a `.` (decimal) it doesn't work. It should only show up to 2 decimal places.

With the current setup I can enter `2000000` and it will get formatted as `2,000,000` which is correct. The issue is if I want to also add cents I am unable to do so. So to do `2000.50` is impossible. This should be `2,000.50`

There is a [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/lrmpw3n9kl) for reference. It may be clearer if you try and enter an amount with decimals there.

Can anyone help here?

My code looks like this:

```
function Input() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");

  const formatValue = value => {
    return setValue(value.replace(/,/g, ""));
  };

  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      value={Number(value).toLocaleString()}
      onChange={e => formatValue(e.target.value)}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here ? Is the conversion with Number and parseFloat really needed on each change ?

Comment: `parseFloat(Number(value).toFixed(2)).toLocaleString()` ???

Comment: oh sorry if it isn't clear, I want to show a currency style input, but to also allow a decimal. If I didnt use Number I was seeing issues

Comment: thanks @BhojendraRauniyar I actually just tried that too, but it doesn't work  Still as issue with entering decimals

Comment: Please show the result and desired result.

Comment: updated the question @BhojendraRauniyar. Hopefully it is clearer now

Comment: This is exactly what you are looking for : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581011/how-to-use-tolocalestring-and-tofixed2-in-javascript

Comment: @sphinxplayer thanks for this, I actually already came across this before I posted but it doesnt work. Unless I am doing something wrong, are you able to get this working in the code sandbox?

Comment: @sphinxplayer here is a link for the code sandbox so you can see how it doesn't work https://codesandbox.io/s/8knjzqzvj2