# toLocaleString not working when value is set to 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript

I have an input where the user can enter a number.  However the number displayed should be set to 2 decimal places while considering the culture.

For example, if the user enter the number 85,

> "85,00"

should be displayed if the culture is french and

> "85.00"

should be displayed if the culture is English.

I have the below code for it:

```
$(document).on("change", ".changeVal", function (e) {
 var valueEntered = parseFloat($(this).val());
 valueEntered = valueEntered.toFixed(2);
 valueEntered = (valueEntered).toLocaleString("fr-FR")
 $(this).val(valueEntered);
});
```

However, this is not setting the input to "85,00".

But when I do,

> console.log((80.22).toLocaleString("fr-FR"));

the displayed value is "80,22";

Any idea of what I might be missing here?

HTML:

```
<input class="mdl-textfield__input text-right placeholder validate-number changeValue" maxlength="150" type="text">
```

Comment: May you share the HTML for `.changeVal`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox : just did

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use toLocaleString() and tofixed(2) in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581011/how-to-use-tolocalestring-and-tofixed2-in-javascript)

Comment: Doesn't `toFixed` convert the number to a string? I don't think `.toLocaleString` will do anything to a string.

Comment: Just use `valueEntered = Number(valueEntered).toLocaleString("fr-FR");`

Answer (score 0):

Just use parseFloat after toFixed because it convert the number to a string.

```
`$(document).on("change", ".changeVal", function (e) {
    var valueEntered = $(this).val();
    valueEntered = parseFloat(valueEntered.toFixed(2));
    valueEntered = (valueEntered).toLocaleString("fr-FR")
    $(this).val(valueEntered);
});`
```