# How to make a number have proper comma formatting AND round to exactly 2 decimals every time in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, currency, cryptocurrency, money-format

I am making a currency converter, and I would like the result to have proper comma formatting as well as ALWAYS rounding to two decimals.

For example, if my number is 1000000.3, I would like the result to be 1,000,000.30.

Is there anything that I am missing? I am very new to coding so any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: not seeing that stack overflow is providing an option to run the code, so you could either copy and paste it into a code editor or open the code here: https://xrpalerts.000webhostapp.com/testing.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>

var CalculatorResult = 1000000.3

var CalculatorResultLocale = parseFloat(CalculatorResult).toLocaleString("us-EN");
var CalculatorResultLocaleFixed = parseFloat(CalculatorResultLocale).toFixed(2);

var CalculatorResultFixed = parseFloat(CalculatorResult).toFixed(2);
var CalculatorResultFixedLocale = parseFloat(CalculatorResultFixed).toLocaleString("us-EN");


function ClickAllResults() {

    document.write("CalculatorResultLocale: ");
    document.write(CalculatorResultLocale);
    document.write("<br>");

    document.write("CalculatorResultLocaleFixed: ");
    document.write(CalculatorResultLocaleFixed);
    document.write("<br>");
    document.write("<br>");

    document.write("CalculatorResultFixed: ");
    document.write(CalculatorResultFixed);
    document.write("<br>");

    document.write("CalculatorResultFixedLocale: ");
    document.write(CalculatorResultFixedLocale);
    document.write("<br>");
}
</script>

<button onclick="ClickAllResults()" id = "button"><strong>Click to see all results</strong></button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `num.toLocaleString(undefined, { minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 })` from the duplicate [How to use toLocaleString() and tofixed(2) in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581011/how-to-use-tolocalestring-and-tofixed2-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display toLocaleString by decimal place use

```
.toLocaleString("us-EN", { minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 })
```

you`r code will be like this

```
var CalculatorResultFixedLocale = parseFloat(CalculatorResultFixed).toLocaleString("us-EN", { minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//execute below function

CommaFormatted('2345643.123')

//result => 2,345,643.123

function CommaFormatted(amount) {
    var delimiter = ","; // replace comma if desired
    var a = amount.split('.',2)
    var d = a[1];
    var i = parseInt(a[0]);
    if(isNaN(i)) { return ''; }
    var minus = '';
    if(i < 0) { minus = '-'; }
    i = Math.abs(i);
    var n = new String(i);
    var a = [];
    while(n.length > 3) {
        var nn = n.substr(n.length-3);
        a.unshift(nn);
        n = n.substr(0,n.length-3);
    }
    if(n.length > 0) { a.unshift(n); }
    n = a.join(delimiter);
    if(d.length < 1) { amount = n; }
    else { amount = n + '.' + d; }
    amount = minus + amount;
    return amount;
}
```

Please refer CSS trick article [https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/comma-values-in-numbers/#:~:text=Javascript%20has%20a%20method%20called,will%20convert%20it%20to%2012%2C345%2C678.90](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/comma-values-in-numbers/#:%7E:text=Javascript%20has%20a%20method%20called,will%20convert%20it%20to%2012%2C345%2C678.90).

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>

var CalculatorResult = 1000000.3
var CalculatorResultMoney = currencyFormat(CalculatorResult);

function ClickAllResults() {
    document.write("CalculatorResultMoney: ");
    document.write(CalculatorResultMoney);
    document.write("<br>");
}

function currencyFormat(num) {
  let a = '$' + num.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,')
  return a;
}
</script>

<button onclick="ClickAllResults()" id = "button"><strong>Click to see all results</strong></button>

</body>
</html>
```

I do find a function similar to your request
https://blog.abelotech.com/posts/number-currency-formatting-javascript/

```
function currencyFormat(num) {
  let a = '$' + num.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,')
  return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

const round = (value, decimals) => {
  return numberWithCommas(Number(Math.round(value + 'e' + decimals) + 'e-' + decimals).toFixed(2));
};

console.log(round(84347.336, 2)); // 84,347.34 
console.log(round(8557.332, 2)); // 8,557.33 
console.log(round(187, 2)); // 187.00
```

The [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method formats a number using fixed-point notation.

Comment: sorry, missed that part, now i updated the answer @Ouroborus please check