# Localized formatting of a number with thousand separators in JavaScript WITH DECIMAL places

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, number-formatting, ecmascript-5

In JavaScript, I have an arbitrary number as input. 
For example:

```
var number = parseFloat(12345678901234.1234567);
```

Now I want to display it as:

```
12'345'678'901'234.12
```

it should be

```
xxx'xxx'xxx.00
```

if it is an integer, and

```
xxx'xxx'xxx.y0
```

if only one digit after the decimal point

I would have assumed that this would do the trick:

```
var number = parseFloat(12345678901234.1234567);

console.log(number.toLocaleString('de-CH', { minimumFractionDigits:2, maximumFractionDigits: 2

}));
```

But it actually displayed `12'345'678'901'234.10` instead of `12'345'678'901'234.12`

So I thought maybe I need to set minimumSignificantDigits to 2, too. 
But bad luck, I discovered minimumSignificantDigits apparently considers all the digits in the string, for whatever idiotic reason, so I need to add the number of digits of the integer part to 2. Like:

```
var number = parseFloat(12345678901234.1234567);


console.log(number.toLocaleString('de-CH', { minimumFractionDigits:2, maximumFractionDigits: 2

,minimumSignificantDigits: parseInt(number).toString().length + 2
}));
```

But this still displays

```
12'345'678'901'234.10
```

Converting the float to the Number type doesn't help either, the output is still the same.

```
var number = Number(parseFloat(12345678901234.1234567));

console.log(number.toLocaleString('de-CH', { minimumFractionDigits:2, maximumFractionDigits: 2

,minimumSignificantDigits: parseInt(number).toString().length + 2
}));
```

I also tried this

```
var number = parseFloat(12345678901234.1234567);
number.toLocaleString('de-CH', {style: 'currency', currency: 'CHF', currencyDisplay: 'code'}).replace('CHF', '')
```

but it does not seem to work either. 
Adding style: "decimal" doesn't help, either...
Additionally, I don't want to have to know the currency name for each locale.

What am I doing wrong ? 
Is there really no other way than writing my own formatting code (where I have the problem that I don't know the thousand separator char for each locale) ? 
Or is this a JavaScript bug for certain ?

Comment: Yep, sorry I re-read the question & removed the comment :)

Comment: @RGraham: No problem. Removed mine, too. But thanks for the indirect link to https://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js , that's very interesting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Format whole numbers using toLocaleString()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21536984/javascript-format-whole-numbers-using-tolocalestring)